# application of the word 'vision' in writing reports

Tags: word-usage

What are the differrences between "vision of" and "vision for"?

If I want to use the word 'vision', is it right to say 'vision for the energy industry in the USA'?

I think they use 'vision for' and 'vision of' in many reports. Are the both of them right expression?

p.s. this is my first question in Stack, please let me know if I'm making mistakes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I have a vision for X* means you want to give X a vision, which typically means you want to transform or move something toward X long-term.  You aren't saying what the vision is.

*I have a vision of X* answers the question of what the vision is.  (But if X is a possessive noun/pronoun, then you are saying you possess a vision of someone else's).

You can knock out two birds with one stone by saying *I have a vision of X for Y.*

Comment: I have a vision of means how you would like to see something, not the way it is.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm still confusing with the usage of it though. For example, is it okay to say "Vision of how it should be regulated for energy industry in the US" as a title of a report? If not, what can be an alternative to it ?